# speedup bandpass filtering along multiple channel eeg signal

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I have 3 hours long 128 channel dataset sampled at 30Khz `128 x 20000000`. I want to filter each channel signal in a specific frequency range say `0-12 Hz`. How can I make this computation fast?

Comment: you can take a look to the `concurrent.futures` module, you can use two classes, that allows you to paralelize your code

Comment: If you can use the `map()` function to get your calculations, then it will be direct for you to paralelize it with the functions provided in the `concurrent.futures` module

Comment: You could add a hardware DSP to your computer.